# How do I Setup (Initialize, Partition, and Format) a disk using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0

What is a basic example of going through the setup of a new disk (Initializing it, partitioning it, and formatting) it using powershell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Step 1: List the Disks Available to the System:**

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.193 -Credential administrator
PS C:\> Get-Disk

Number Friendly Name                            OperationalStatus                    Total Size Partition Style
------ -------------                            -----------------                    ---------- ---------------
0      Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device          Online                                    20 GB MBR
1      Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device          Offline                                    2 GB RAW
```

**Step 2: Initialize the Disk:**

`[192.168.1.193]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> Initialize-Disk -Number 1`

The disk will now show a Partition Style (GBP) when repeating `Get-Disk`:

```
1      Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device   Online    2 GB GPT
```

**Step 3: Setup a Partition**:

```
PS C:\> New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter


Disk Number: 1

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset        Size     Type
---------------  ----------- ------        ----     ----
2                D           33619968      1.97 GB  Basic
```

**Step 4: Format the Volume:**

```
PS C:\> Format-Volume -DriveLetter D

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Warning, all data on the volume will be lost!
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y

DriveLetter       FileSystemLabel  FileSystem       DriveType        HealthStatus        SizeRemaining             Size
-----------       ---------------  ----------       ---------        ------------        -------------             ----
D                                  NTFS             Fixed            Healthy                   1.92 GB          1.97 GB
```

See the [storage cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848705.aspx) to find out more with disk management using powershell.